# Groovy syntax to parse data from XML

Tags: java, parsing, xpath, groovy, soapui

I need to get the value 3 from the below xml file using groovy script.
I am testing from SOAPUI

```
 <ParamId>3</ParamId>
```

Can anyone please share me the syntax to get the value?
I tried the following code. But I think I need to iterate to the third Param..

```
def msgTxt = response.getDomNode("//ns2:ParamId").getLastChild().getNodeValue()  



<RequestParams>
            <Param>
               <ParamId>1</ParamId>
               <ParamName>Name1</ParamName>
               <ParamType>String</ParamType>
               <ParamValue>value1</ParamValue>
            </Param>
            <Param>
               <ParamId>2</ParamId>
               <ParamName>Name2</ParamName>
               <ParamType>String</ParamType>
               <ParamValue>value2</ParamValue>
            </Param>
            <Param>
               <ParamId>3</ParamId>
               <ParamName>Name3</ParamName>
               <ParamType>String</ParamType>
               <ParamValue>2</ParamValue>
            </Param>
</RequestParams>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using groovy scripts then this will work.

`parse.groovy`

```
import org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.shaded.xml.XmlStreamReader
/**
 * @author maba, 2012-08-24
 */

def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(new XmlStreamReader(new File('path/to/data', 'data.xml')))
def msgText = root.Param[2].ParamId.text()
```

And I think you can do this instead of reading from file:

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response.xmlText())
```

But I am not sure what the type of `response` is. Here I assumed an [`XmlTokenSource`](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlTokenSource.html) from `XmlBeans`.

---

This should work for SoapUI `XmlHolder`:

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response.getXml())
```

Comment: I added the part for SoapUI. The XmlSlurper is really nice and uses [GPath](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GPath) expressions to navigate in the XML tree.

Comment: Hi maba,Can you please answer this question if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106955/groovy-script-to-get-the-request-xml. Sorry I am actually need to get the values from the request xml

Answer (score 2):

Check out XmlParser or XmlSlurper examples in Groovy [documentation page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Processing+XML)