# Groovy script to get the request xml

Tags: java, xml, parsing, groovy, soapui

I can get the response xml using Groovy script. I need to get the request XML since I need to add 'assertion script' to my soap ui testing.

I am using the following code to get the response xml

```
def response = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)
```

But I am not sure how to get the request xml of SOAPUI. Can anyone please help me in getting the request xml of SOPAUI?

Comment: How about `messageExchange.requestContentAsXml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the request content as a string you can use

```
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Name of your teststeup"].testRequest.response.getRequestContent()
```

More information on the SoapUI API can be found at http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?overview-summary.html. Have a look at the Request and Response class in particular for the methods and properties they provide

Comment: Note that if the test step has never been run, the `response` will be null, but you can use: `testStep.testRequest.getRequestContent()` instead.

Comment: Note also that the request content from the testStep is pre-tokenised (if you are using `${#TestCase#property_name}` type property expansion), so in order to get the post-tokenised content, you'll have to use `messageExchange.requestContent`